# Scrape data from website into dataframe(s) using Split function

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

**Outline:**

This code uses the `Split` function to extract specific information from the following website: https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/tables.

The required information are the four tables visible on the page with headers `"#", "First Name","Last Name","Username"`.  I am extracting the information within these into 4 dataframes.

---

**Example table:**

[image: table1]

---

**Description:**

I use the `requests` library to make the `GET` request, and split the response text on `"table table-bordered"` to generate my individual table chunks.

There is a fair amount of annoying fiddly indexing to get just the info I want, but the tutorial I am following requires the use of the `Split` function, and not something far more logical, to my mind, like Beautiful Soup, where I could just apply CSS selectors, for example, and grab what I want. The latter method would be less fragile as well.

I have written a function, `GetTable`, to parse the required information from each chunk and return a dataframe. There is a difference between the `Split` delimiter for table 1 versus 2-4.

There isn't an awful lot of code but I would appreciate any pointers on improving the code I have written.

I am running this from Spyder 3.2.8 with Python 3.6.

---

**Code:**

```
def GetTable(tableChunk):
    split1 = tableChunk.split('tbody')[1]
    split2 = split1.split('<table')[0]
    values = []

    aList = split2.split('>\n\t\t\t\t<') 
    if len(aList) !=1:
        for item in aList[1:]:
                values.append(item.split('</')[0].split('d>'[1])[1])
    else:
        aList = split2.split('</td')
        for item in aList[:-1]:
           values.append(item.split('td>')[1])

    headers =  ["#", "First Name", "Last Name", "User Name"]  
    numberOfColumns = len(headers)
    numberOfRows = int((len(values) / numberOfColumns))

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(values).reshape( numberOfRows, numberOfColumns ) , columns = headers)
    return df

import requests as req
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "http://webscraper.io/test-sites/tables"
response = req.get(url)
htmlText = response.text  
tableChunks = htmlText.split('table table-bordered')

for tableChunk in tableChunks[1:]:
   print(GetTable(tableChunk))
   print('\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't parse HTML manually, you should use the [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module!
2. `import` should be at the top of the file
3. Use a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard
4. Functions and variable should be `snake_case`

---

First you can rewrite the `getTable()` alot using the `BeautifulSoup` module

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://webscraper.io/test-sites/tables"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
for table in soup.select('.table'):
    new_table = [[c.text for c in row.find_all('td')] for row in table.find_all('tr')]
```

The only problem is that it will also give back None values in the table, so we'd need to catch the None values and only yield when the list is not filled with None

## Revised Code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_table(table):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        col = [c.text for c in row.find_all('td')]
        if not all(c is None for c in col):
            yield col

def scrape_tables():
    url = "http://webscraper.io/test-sites/tables"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    for table in soup.select('.table'):
        parsed_table = [col for col in parse_table(table)]
        df = pd.DataFrame(parsed_table, columns=["#", "First Name", "Last Name", "User Name"])
        print()
        print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape_tables()
```

Comment: Thank you I will have a proper look later today. The tutorial requires parsing in this manner which I agree is ludicrous. It is not how I woud do it. It is akin to trying to regex your way through it. I do appreciate seeing a BS4 example and will feedback.

Comment: A tutorial who learns you to use `split` for html parsing is a bad one, if you don't mind me saying. No point in teaching yourself bad habits [Code Horros](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) :)

Comment: Agreed. I am hoping it will improve. My feedback has not been positive to the organisation concerned so far.

Comment: Very helpful + 1. I will see if any further points are raised but will get back to you.

Comment: Accepted this due to the variety of points you address with my code. Thank you for taking the time to review

Answer (score 2):

If the table is properly formatted (same column layout) you can do this in one line (read the html and format into a DataFrame):

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_html("https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites/tables")
```

Of course there are four tables on this page, so `result` becomes a list:

```
    In [7]: for item in result:
   ...:     print("\n-------------------------------------")
   ...:     print(item)
   ...:

-------------------------------------
   # First Name Last Name  Username
0  1       Mark      Otto      @mdo
1  2      Jacob  Thornton      @fat
2  3      Larry  the Bird  @twitter

-------------------------------------
   # First Name Last Name  Username
0  4      Harry    Potter       @hp
1  5       John      Snow    @dunno
2  6        Tim      Bean  @timbean

-------------------------------------
   0           1          2         3
0  #  First Name  Last Name  Username
1  1        Mark       Otto      @mdo
2  2       Jacob   Thornton      @fat
3  3       Larry   the Bird  @twitter

-------------------------------------
     0           1          2         3
0  NaN      Person  User data       NaN
1    #  First Name  Last Name  Username
2    -           -          -         -
3    1        Mark       Otto      @mdo
4    2       Jacob   Thornton      @fat
5    3       Larry   the Bird  @twitter
```

Obviously as the last table has merged cells, the last result is messy.

Comment: That is awesome. I expected this kind of easy grabbing option from python as I am used to it with other languages (doesn't always work but good to have in the toolbox) and here we go. +1